# When triggering a function in another view the view renders twice

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have two views in my app, first view is a modal dialog and a second view is where the modal gets triggered from initially. After closing the modal I am triggering a function in the second view using trigger event function. The function in the second view gets triggered however it re renders the entire second view twice. I have read about zombie views and made sure to unbind and remove the modal view in case it was causing duplicate events but that did not work.

Here is my my modal view class:

```js
var BaseModalView = base.views.View.extend({
  tpl: templates.get('modalTmp'),
  className: 'modal-view',
  events: {
    'evt:show': 'show',
    'evt:hide': 'hide',
    'click [data-action=resume-push-market]': 'proceed',
  },
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'show', 'hide', 'remove');
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {

    this.$el.html(this.tpl(this.options));
    this.$el.appendTo('body');
    this.$modal = this.$('.modal');

    this.$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', _.bind(function() {
      this.close();
    }, this));


  },
  show: function() {
    this.$modal.modal('show');
  },
  hide: function() {
    this.$modal.modal('hide');
  },
  proceed: function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.hide();
    this.vent.trigger('resume', true);
  },
  close: function() {
    //unbind events
    this.unbind();
    //Remove html from page
    this.remove();
  },

});
export default BaseModalView;
```

This is how I listen for a trigger on the second view:

```
this.listenTo(this.vent,'resume', this.resume);
```

After some debugging I noticed that the modal view gets unbound and removed only after the second view is rendered twice after the function is triggered. I'm not sure if this is normal behaviour as I am very new to Backbone.js. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I think I have narrowed down to what is causing the extra renders. The second view is an item in a collection, so if that collection only has one item i.e. one view, then when my function is triggered from the modal it will re render that view once. However if there are multiple views in the collection then each view will get re rendered when the function is triggered. I have initialised the modal view in each item in the collection so technically it should only re render that one item(view) in the collection but it re renders them all every time. Again not sure if I am understating the backbone event sequences correctly, If anyone has encountered a similar problem please let me know

Comment: Where is the second view? what is in `this.resume`? Please see [mcve]

Comment: Its not really important whats in that function, it performs some logic in that view. I have tested that function by only having a console.log('got here'); statement in it and it triggers as many times as there are views in the collection

Comment: Well then it is important what is in the view....

Comment: I can't post that code here as its proprietary. I can say that its initialised the same way as the modal view and every time any kind of change occurs in that view it gets re rendered. Just for context, if I take out the modal out of the equation and trigger that resume function from within the view it will only re render that view once

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around this by passing an originating view model options into the modal view then once the function is triggered and views are re rendering I make sure that only the view that originated the modal gets updated with the intended information by comparing the view ID's. This is a very dirty way of doing this I'm sure.